# How do I add an existing XCode (4.5) project to BitBucket

Tags: objective-c, ios, git, svn, bitbucket

I have an existing project in XCode 4.5 which is not under any form of source control.  All I want to do is add it to a BitBucket repository so that I can work alongside another developer.

I've tried and tried to get this code under source control and onto a BitBucket repository, but I just can't seem to nail it.

Could someone please talk me through it, step-by-step.

- I've created a repository in BitBucket and it's waiting for my code.
- To create the repository localled, I ran `git init`, `git add .` and `git commit -m 'Initial version'` on the relevant directory.
- BitBucket suggests that I run `hg push` to import an existing repository, but I get the following error:

  - abort: no repository found in '/Users/xxx/Documents/Dev/projectname' (.hg not found)!

If I go into XCode, I have a repository showing in the Organizer.  But it's not connected with BitBucket at all.

All help very gratefully received.  Thanks.

Comment: `hg push` is a Mercurial command, and you're setting up a Git repository earlier in your question. I'm sure there must be a BitBucket help page describing the process, but the site is down for me at the moment.

Comment: OK thanks Paul. I've looked around for a BitBucket page, found a few things, but they all lead me to dead-ends!  How does one push a GIT repository?

Comment: @NikosM has provided the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add your bitbucket repository as a remote to your local one. You can do this by running

> git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:*userName/repositoryName.git*.

You then need to push your local files to the remote repo by running

> git push origin master

Note that this will push them to the master branch on the bitbucket repo.

Answer (score 2):

While not perfect, I've found [SourceTree](http://blog.bitbucket.org/2011/10/06/sourcetree-mac-client-acquired-by-atlassian/) to be very helpful with BitBucket.

Comment: Yeah! I'm actually using that now, although I still use the init/add/commit/remote calls to set everything up first.  Thanks.

Comment: it works with Git too, and have a nice diff utility; and it's FREE